# AngularJS error not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so i have a simple html and angular js but for some reason its not working, and its getting really annoying!

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="C:\Users\Ghaith Haddad\Desktop\MyApp\">
<script src="\app.js"></script>
<script src="angular-1.6.6\angular.min.js"></script>
<title>plz work</title>
</head>
<body ng-app='myapp'>
<div ng-controller='wtf'>
<h1>{{carname}}</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the js code, app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller("wtf", function($scope) {
$scope.carname = "Volvo";
});
```

can someone pleaaasssee tell me why the heck this thing isn't working??
here is a pic of the error i get

[image]

Comment: Change order of scripts. angular.js must load before you try to use `angular` object

Answer (score 1):

There's two possible problem that you can encounter here.

**1st** is that you are loading your **app.js** before your `angularjs` script.

**2nd** possible error is that maybe your calling the wrong **app.js** path.

Comment: Error wouldn't specify app.js line 1 if #2 was true

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="angular-1.6.6\angular.min.js"></script>
```

This should be place before

```
<script src="\app.js"></script>
```

Reasons:

1.The definitions $scope,module,controller are in angular.min.js 
 2. You have used app.js before angular.min.js So your app.js won't have
    any definitions for $scope,module,controller